# Why do browsers (chromium-based and firefox) prefer gzip over brotli?

Tags: browser, header, gzip, brotli

I have tested a few browsers (namely firefox, edge, chrome and chromium, in their mobile and desktop versions) and found that each of them sent the following `accept-encoding` header value: `gzip, deflate, br` when performing a request.

According to [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding), this header field consists of a list of encodings supported by the browser, in order of preference. What surprises me is that brotli (`br`) is listed last, which means that it is less likely to be the selected algorithm for content-encoding than `gzip` even though it should achieve a better compression ratio.

Is there a specific reason as to why browser tends to prefer gzip over brotli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing anywhere in the specifications that the ordering has any meaning. To the contrary, I see that a preference can only be expressed by providing quality weights for the encoding, *and* that providing such preferences from the client side is discouraged. It is up to the server to pick among the choices that the client can accept, however it likes.

Comment: Well, the documentation about q-values doesn't really clarify that, but says "If there is no priority defined for the first two values, the order in the list is irrelevant. Nevertheless, with the same quality, more specific values have priority over less specific ones:". So I guess in this case you're right there's no real order. The question is more "is there a reason as to why brotli was put last ?" in this case. I initially assumed that items without explicit q-values were ordered because it was the case in two http library I used.

Comment: Source e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding